# Regex sublime file search

Tags: javascript, regex, django-templates

I hope this will be a simple regex question, I'm trying to find regex for searching django files (sublimetext) with wrong {% if ... endif %} syntax.

The problem is wrong equality test:

```
{% if a = b %}<script> a = b; </script>{% endif %}
{% if a == b %}<script> a = b; </script>{% endif %}
```

First is not correct, second is OK, I tried:

```
{% if (.*?) = (.*?) %}
```

pattern witch returns me second line in results.

Maybe this will help [django problem link](https://regexr.com/3iqqi). Second line shouldn't be selected

Thanx

Comment: So you're trying to replace all `if a=b` occurrences with `if a==b`?

Comment: Not replace, just want to find all similar cases. a = b is only for example. Real cases are much complexed. Django part is I want to find {% if a = b %}

Comment: So what types of things are you hoping to match? Both lines 1 and 2? All `{% if ... %}`?

Comment: OK, multiline is not a problem. I have a bunch of files that have some form of that error.

    {% if a = b %}<script> var a = b; </script>{% endif %}

also, it can be

    {% if list.length = 12 %}, {% if "correct equality" = 'False' %}.

I have wrong results when django is OK {% if == %} but "=" sign is part of the same line (second line in an example). I have to manually check all files because of possibility that OK django  {% if == %} throws false result because JS is assigning some variable  (or some other "=" scenario) in the same line.

Comment: I miss multiline in comments. Maybe this will help [django problem link](https://regexr.com/3iqqi). Second line shouldnt be selected

Comment: did one of our answers help you or do you still need a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe something like this?

```
{%\s*if[^=]+=[^=]+%}
```

It should match only the first line

Answer (score 0):

`{% if (.*?) ==? (.*?) %}`

Should match all types of if statements that have either 1 or 2 equals signs.